# css fallback for material icons

Tags: html, css, material-design, frontend, web-frontend

Browsers like Firefox on Android give their user the ability to manually disable web fonts which basically means web fonts will not be downloaded. I am using the material design tick mark for rendering check mark inside a design.

The css looks like

```
font-family: 'Material Icons';
content: "done";
```

Is there a way to give a fallback for this `content`?

Answer (score 1):

Could you use the Unicode tick mark?

http://graphemica.com/%E2%9C%94

`content: "\2714";`
or
`content: "✔";`

If you worried that there is no Unicode support - I think having a text message like "done" or using an image would work.

**Update**:

If you are worried about people blocking fonts - then use the PNG Sprites:
https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/sprites

Comment: I am trying to use the material icon - "done" . The way I am doing this is working absolutely fine for all browsers and screens except for browsers where people have manually disabled downloading web fonts.

Comment: If you can't use a font  then download / use the SVG or PNG version

Answer (score 0):

You could try this solution from github. It uses jQuery to replace the font icons with background-images: http://dfcb.github.io/iconfont-fallback/

Another possibility would be to use SVG sprites: http://maddesigns.de/svg-sprites-icon-fonts-2309.html